# Google Checkout button not appearing on cart page

Tags: magento

Hope you guys don't mind me asking this question, but I find myself at a loss to why this is happening and need some suggestions on how I might resolve the issue. If I shouldn't ask these kinds of questions, please let me know.

Currently I am working on a Magento 1.9 site that was upgraded from 1.8 and when I enabled Google Checkout, the button doesn't appear on the cart page (/checkout/cart/). I went back to the default template that Magento uses and it still didn't work.

I then tried enabling Google Checkout on a clean copy of Magento 1.9 and it worked. Then I tried replacing the core mage checkout folder with the ones from the clean copy of Magento and that didn't work.

So I have test the layout, template and core mage checkout files and nothing happens.
I also tried accessing Google Checkout directly with this piece of code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('googlecheckout/link')->setTemplate('googlecheckout/link.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, turn the default template on for testing, just to be sure. Clear all your caches and try again. Make sure that there aren't any "hidden" elements on the page displaying it. It may be helpful to turn on template hints to see if the block exists as anticipated but does not render any content, or if the block actually does not exist as anticipated.

If no joy, check to make sure that Google's critera are met. Taking a look at that template and block, there are a few checks that need to pass to get checkout:

1. `Mage::getModel('googlecheckout/payment')->isAvailable($quote)`
2. `$quote->validateMinimumAmount()`
3. Every single product in the cart must return false to `$item->getProduct()->getEnableGooglecheckout()` (otherwise, ti looks like the template wants to display an image)

Report back if you still have problems :)

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thank you so much! When you said that every product needed to have it enabled, I was able to track down a custom module that was turning it off.